# UINavigationController popView behavior

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

i'm writing an iPhone app and i'm having problems with a UINavigationController bug that i can't replicate at will.

I have 3 table views and at the end a detail / normal UIView. Occasionally when i navigate back from the detail view back into the table views it does something a bit weird:

The title will animate (so it will do the slidy thing and the title will change back to what is expected), but the content doesn't.

(Titles v Content)

```
T1     ->     T2      ->     T3     ->     D1

T1Content     T2Content      T3Content     D1Content          [Hit Back Button]

T1     <-     T2      <-     T3     <-

T2Content     T3Content      T3Content
```

And then go back further and it's a SEG_FAULT.

I'm sure this is me doing something weird along the way - but i don't really know what, so any suggestions on what mistakes might manifest themselves this way would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,

Pete.

edit - include code:

```
// Push view code
[self.navigationController pushViewController:updateController animated:YES];
[updateController release];     

// Pop view code
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Could you some code so we can see how you are pushing/popping the view controllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wasn't pushing the content twice - it was some code that tried to get the T2 view to remove a row, but in the nice table way. only way i did that was to store a temporary variable when T3 had finished, and then execute the table delete after the view had loaded - and something in that whole process wasn't right, but manifested itself like described.

odd.

thanks anyway,

pete.